# Can I access the images from my iCloud account from my Asp.Net website

Tags: iphone, icloud

I would like to access my photos in iCloud from a webiste running Asp.Net.

Is there a way to access them outside of the web interface?

Answer (score 1):

You could access the public link of your shared photostream, parse the HTML, and get the pictures from the iCloud server. You would need to save this files to your server or database (as stream or blob datatype).